# Google Charts LineChart Permanent Annotations Above Points using Ajax and JS

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, google-visualization

I am racking my brain trying to understand how to do Ajax with Annotations in a Line Chart from Google Charts.  I am looking for the numbers to sit direct above each point.

Information provided by grab_twitter_stats.php

```
[15, 194, 194],[14, 169, 169],[13, 155, 155],[12, 185, 185],[11, 154, 154],[10, 154, 154],[9, 135, 135],[8, 176, 176],[7, 193, 193],[6, 198, 198],[5, 185, 185],[4, 204, 204],[3, 219, 219],[2, 254, 254],[1, 230, 230],
```

Google Graphs Code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    drawChart();
    setInterval(drawChart, (20000));

    function drawChart() {
      $.ajax({
        url: 'grab_twitter_stats.php',
        type: 'get',
        success: function (txt) {
          // check for trailing comma
          if (txt.slice(-1) === ',') {
            txt = txt.substring(0, txt.length - 1);
          }
          var txtData = JSON.parse('[["Minutes", "Tweets", ""],' + txt + ']');
          ;

          var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(txtData);
          data.addColumn('number', 'Minutes');
          data.addColumn('number', 'Tweets');
          data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'annotation'});
          //alert(data);
          var options = {
            curveType: 'function',
            hAxis: {
            format: '#',
            baseline:15,
              direction: '-1',
                textStyle: {
                    color: '#7acdd0',
                    fontSize: 20
                },
              gridlines: {
                    color: 'transparent'
                },
              viewWindow:{
                    max:15,
                    min:1
                },
            },
            vAxis: {
                baseline:0,
                gridlines: {
                    color: 'transparent'
                },
                textStyle: {
                    color: '#7acdd0',
                    fontSize: 20
                }
            },
            pointSize: 15,
            chartArea: {'width': '89%', 'height': '65%'},
            pointShape: 'circle',
            lineWidth: 5,
            colors: ['#7acdd0'],
            annotations: {
                textStyle: {
                  fontName: 'Times-Roman',
                  fontSize: 18,
                  bold: true,
                  italic: true,
                  color: '#871b47',     // The color of the text.
                  auraColor: '#d799ae', // The color of the text outline.
                  opacity: 0.8          // The transparency of the text.
                }
              },
            legend: { position: 'none' }
          };

          var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('curve_chart'));
          chart.draw(data, options);
        }
      });
    }
  },
  packages: ['corechart']
});
      
</script>
```

The end display looks something like this:
[image: Google Chart]

You can also see here that ToolTips are working, but it provides the name for whatever I set the 3rd item to in JSON.parse.

[image: Google Chart with Tooltips]

What am I missing?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

need to adjust how the DataTable is built

---

currently, the table is created using `arrayToDataTable`

```
var txtData = JSON.parse('[["Minutes", "Tweets", ""],' + txt + ']');
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(txtData);
```

this creates the table with 3 columns and all the rows

then 3 more columns are added

```
data.addColumn('number', 'Minutes');
data.addColumn('number', 'Tweets');
data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'annotation'});
```

but no data is ever provided to these columns

---

instead, create a blank table, then add the columns and rows...

```
var txtData = JSON.parse('[' + txt + ']');

var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('number', 'Minutes');
data.addColumn('number', 'Tweets');
data.addColumn({type: 'number', role: 'annotation'});
data.addRows(txtData);
```

be sure to remove the column definitions from `txtData`
also, for the annotation, you should probably use --> `type: 'number'`
or change the type in the array being passed --> `[15, 194, "194"]`

---

see following working snippet...
(using static data but will translate back to ajax just the same)

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var txt = "[15, 194, 194],[14, 169, 169],[13, 155, 155],[12, 185, 185],[11, 154, 154],[10, 154, 154],[9, 135, 135],[8, 176, 176],[7, 193, 193],[6, 198, 198],[5, 185, 185],[4, 204, 204],[3, 219, 219],[2, 254, 254],[1, 230, 230]";
    var txtData = JSON.parse('[' + txt + ']');

    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('number', 'Minutes');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Tweets');
    data.addColumn({type: 'number', role: 'annotation'});
    data.addRows(txtData);

    var options = {
      curveType: 'function',
      hAxis: {
      format: '#',
      baseline:15,
        direction: '-1',
          textStyle: {
              color: '#7acdd0',
              fontSize: 20
          },
        gridlines: {
              color: 'transparent'
          },
        viewWindow:{
              max:15,
              min:1
          },
      },
      vAxis: {
          baseline:0,
          gridlines: {
              color: 'transparent'
          },
          textStyle: {
              color: '#7acdd0',
              fontSize: 20
          }
      },
      pointSize: 15,
      chartArea: {'width': '89%', 'height': '65%'},
      pointShape: 'circle',
      lineWidth: 5,
      colors: ['#7acdd0'],
      annotations: {
          textStyle: {
            fontName: 'Times-Roman',
            fontSize: 18,
            bold: true,
            italic: true,
            color: '#871b47',     // The color of the text.
            auraColor: '#d799ae', // The color of the text outline.
            opacity: 0.8          // The transparency of the text.
          }
        },
      legend: { position: 'none' }
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('curve_chart'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  },
  packages: ['corechart']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="curve_chart"></div>
```